# iPod Touch 1st Gen songs stuck on repeat

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod

My iPod touch (1st gen) is stuck on repeat. I can't figure out how to turn off the repeat function. All i see is the shuffle option in the songs section.

Answer (score 1):

So I stumbled upon a solution. I clicked on "Now Playing" After which I clicked on the "Play" button to start the song. Staying in portrait mode I touched the screen once (where the default song icon is) and the song time along with the shuffle and repeat option slid down. I was able to turn off repeat from there by clicking on the "repeat" option (it turned from blue to white color")